# Do we require Visio services to edit the Visio file?

Tags: document-library, check-out, check-in, visio, services

I tried to check out a Visio file and edit it. But I am unable to save the changes.

*Note: Visio service is not running on my system

Comment: **But I am unable to save the changes**. What is the extact behavior?

Comment: It is not allowing me to save any changes done on the Visio file to the SharePoint as it works for MS-Word document

Comment: This issue is on certain libraries... How to fix it?